# Temperature of the surface of the sun?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, astrophysics, temperature, sun, stars

I recently had an exam question that asked for the temperature at the surface of the sun. The question is 
[image]

The equation I believe you have to use is 
[image]

The Q/t is the radiant power produced by the sun.

On our equation sheet, we are given the lowercase sigma constant = 5.67 x 10^-8

We can use the mass of the sun to solve

The only part I am unable to find that we are missing is the emissivity.

After that, you can solve for T. But I can't find the emissivity. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you, and sorry for any horrible formatting, as I composed this on my phone.

Comment: Assume that the sun is a ideal [black body](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_body) e = 1.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know ideal black body means it has perfect emissivity. That gets the right answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula
$$ L = \epsilon A \sigma T^4,$$
where $L$ is the luminosity in Watts, 
can be used for a "grey body" i.e. one that has a constant emissivity with frequency.

Here you were told to "assume the Sun to be a perfect blackbody". This means that its emissivity is 1 because a blackbody absorbs everthing incident upon it and because it is in thermal equilibrium must radiate it all back as a blackbody spectrum.

Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law